# Move a Production Switch from One Rack to Another

Tags: switch, rack

Is there any good way to move a live, production switch from one rack to a second, nearby rack? The switch does have redundant power supplies, plus we have a HotPlug (http://www.wiebetech.com/products/HotPlug.php) so I wouldn't think that power should be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

[This is how it is done for a server](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ5MA685ApE) without all the fancy stuff you have.

A switch would be more of a challenge, especially if the hosts connected to it do *not* have a redundant connection. Even if you don't have to power it off, you very likely would need to disconnect and re-route the data cables.